# Google Sheets and External API

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I have the following code which is giving me an error,
I understand that google sheets script does not use `XMLHttpRequest`

Can someone assist?

> ReferenceError: "XMLHttpRequest" is not defined. (line 2, file "Code")

```
function myFunction() {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.open('GET', 'https://inventory.dearsystems.com/ExternalApi/v2/product?Page=1&Limit=1000');

request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
request.setRequestHeader('api-auth-accountid', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,');
request.setRequestHeader('api-auth-applicationkey', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx');

request.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (this.readyState === 4) {
    console.log('Status:', this.status);
    console.log('Headers:', this.getAllResponseHeaders());
    console.log('Body:', this.responseText);
  }
};

request.send();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)

```
function myFunction() {
  var url = 'https://inventory.dearsystems.com/ExternalApi/v2/product?Page=1&Limit=1000';
  var options = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'api-auth-accountid': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      'api-auth-applicationkey': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    }
  }
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  console.log(response.getContentText())
}
```

Comment: Thank you very very much......that worked, Is there a way to get the information into google sheets ie spreadsheet form?

Comment: Read Google's docs. 
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues

Comment: @StephenJohnson - Yes, if your function returns a value, then this will be outputted back to the google Sheet, just put "=myFunction()" in the cell, Here's a demo https://blog.dotnetframework.org/2019/11/29/call-an-api-from-within-googlesheets/